# U-SQL extraction failure for gz with custom JsonExtractor

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am getting an exception during extraction whilst attempting to use the custom `JsonExtractor` from the `Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats` library with a gzipped file.

```
Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.ScopeDebugExceptionwasunhandledMessage: Anunhandledexceptionoftype'Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.ScopeDebugException'occurredinMicrosoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.dllAdditionalinformation: {
    "diagnosticCode": 195887142,
    "severity": "Error",
    "component": "RUNTIME",
    "source": "User",
    "errorId": "E_RUNTIME_USER_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION_FROM_USER_CODE",
    "message": "An unhandled exception from user code has been reported when invoking the method 'Extract' on the user type 'Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor'",
    "description": "Unhandled exception from user code: \"Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: j. Path '', line 1, position 33.\"\nThe details includes more information including any inner exceptions and the stack trace where the exception was raised.",
    "resolution": "Make sure the bug in the user code is fixed.",
    "helpLink": "",
    "details": "==== Caught exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberIntoBuffer()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber(ReadType readType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
       at Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor.<Extract>d__2.MoveNext()
       at ScopeEngine.SqlIpExtractor<ScopeEngine::GZipInput,Extract_0_Data0>.GetNextRow(SqlIpExtractor<ScopeEngine::GZipInput23644,Extract_0_Data0>* , Extract_0_Data0* output) in c:23644projects23644data-insights23644data_insights_ingestion_service23644datainsights.internalbi.scripts23644bin23644debug23644746497ac301de51323644n-populateaccountcurrencycodes.usql.debug_6b364b066929ac9723644sqlmanaged.h:line 1873",
    "internalDiagnostics": ""
}
```

The extraction is successful if the JSON files are passed without gzipping them.

I have also tested gzipped csv files, they seem to work just fine.
This is encountered during a LocalRun. I haven't submitted this particular script to the cloud yet.

Comment: Could you please share your USQL script as well? I'm currently using the same assembly without any issues.

Comment: @PaulAndrew are you using a compressed(gzip) zipped archive (*.tar.gz) with the `JsonExtractor` ?
An example of what I am trying to do is:

`EXTRACT 
            prop_1    string,
            prop_2    string 
        FROM  @"/json/sampleJsonFiles.tar.gz"
        USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor()) AS a`

Answer (score 1):

sponturious,

What version of Azure Data Lake Tools you use when that issue happens (the latest is 2.2.5000.0)?  Also, could you please try "gzip -t  your_gzip_data.gz" to validate the integrity of the gzip file ?

gzip for windows can be get from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm

Thanks,
Yu Dong

Comment: I am using the latest version, the issue isn't with the gz file, but with reading in archived entities as a gz file.
It works fine with the built-in extractors for e.g: csv extractor, but not with the `JsonExtractor` that is included in the `Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats` namespace, I have solved the issue with writing a custom extractor to unarchive the context prior to json extraction

Comment: @sponturious gz file should be unpacked on the fly normally. I tried with the sample from GitHub and it looks ok.
`REFERENCE ASSEMBLY JSONBlog.[Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY JSONBlog.[Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats]; 

USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;

@data =
    EXTRACT
        id       string,  
        Revision string,       
        Camera   string        
    FROM @"/Samples/Blogs/MRys/JSON/camera.json.gz"
    USING new JsonExtractor();`

Comment: it is able to do it for a single json file but not multiple JSON files gzipped together such as in "cameras.tar.gz", where "cameras.tar" would contain multiple json files.